# Slim - Como devolver un json en un solo array (Se me crea doble array)

Tags: php, json

Tengo un problema a la hora de devolver en JSON los resultados que quiero. Hago una consulta a la base de datos y cuando rescato ya esa respuesta la guardo en un array y así hasta tres veces, o sea, que quiero que me devuelva un JSON de tres filas. Mi problema está en que me crea un doble array al hacer un `json_encode`.

Estoy usando Slim un microframeWork de PHP.

Mi código:

```
$app->get('/obtenerLasTresPreguntas', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $ArrayTresPreguntas = [];
    $Preguntas = Preguntas::get();
    $CountPreguntas = Preguntas::count();

    $array = randomGen(1,$CountPreguntas,3);

    foreach ($array as &$valor) {
        $Pregunta = Preguntas::where('id', '=', $valor)->get();
        array_push($ArrayTresPreguntas,$Pregunta);
    }

    return json_encode(array_values($ArrayTresPreguntas));
});
```

Y me devuelve este array doble...

```
[
    [{
        "id": 5,
        "pregunta": "Cosas que provocan estornudos",
        "respuesta": "Polvo,Comida,Irritaci\u00f3n nariz,Mocos,Canela,Virus,Contaminaci\u00f3n,Poluci\u00f3n,Resfriado,Flores,Catarro,Invierno,\u00c1caros,Perfume fuerte,Viento,Moho,Perros,H\u00famedad,H\u00e1mster,Conejos,Fumar,Especias,Heno,Guindilla,Constipado,Alergia a los \u00e1caros,Enfermedades,Lim\u00f3n,Polen,Naranja,Fr\u00edo,Infecci\u00f3n nasal,Pluma,Gripe,Bacterias,Pinos,Pelo,Aire fr\u00edo,Animales,Rinitis,Luz,Aire,Lluvia,Agua,Tierra,Escalofr\u00edo,Reflejos,Caballos,Pimienta,Pelusas,Olor,Cebolla"
    }],
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "pregunta": "Top 10 personas m\u00e1s ricas",
        "respuesta": "Amancio Ortega,Bill Gates,David Koch,Mark Zuckerberg,Warren Buffett,Carlos Slim,Charles Koch,Larry Ellison,Jeff Bezos,Bernard Arnault"
    }],
    [{
        "id": 4,
        "pregunta": "Actores principales de Harry Potter",
        "respuesta": "Daniel Radcliffe,Emma Watson,Harry Mellings,Rupert Grint,Tom Felton,Oliver Phelps,Fiona Shaw,Maggie Smith,Evanna Lynch,Jason Isaacs,Devon Murray,Ralph Fiennes,Jame Phelps,Gary Oldman,David Bradley,Matthew Lewis,Richard Griffiths,Michael Gambon,Alfred Enoch,Bonnie Wright,Alan Rickman,Richard Bremmer,Richard Harris,Helena Bonham Carter,Robbie Coltrane,Robert Pattinson"
    }]
]
```

Y yo quiero que me llegue a devolver exactamente igual pero sin el array anterior, que sería de esta manera (es quitando el primer corchete y el último):

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "pregunta": "Cosas que provocan estornudos",
    "respuesta": "Polvo,Comida,Irritaci\u00f3n nariz,Mocos,Canela,Virus,Contaminaci\u00f3n,Poluci\u00f3n,Resfriado,Flores,Catarro,Invierno,\u00c1caros,Perfume fuerte,Viento,Moho,Perros,H\u00famedad,H\u00e1mster,Conejos,Fumar,Especias,Heno,Guindilla,Constipado,Alergia a los \u00e1caros,Enfermedades,Lim\u00f3n,Polen,Naranja,Fr\u00edo,Infecci\u00f3n nasal,Pluma,Gripe,Bacterias,Pinos,Pelo,Aire fr\u00edo,Animales,Rinitis,Luz,Aire,Lluvia,Agua,Tierra,Escalofr\u00edo,Reflejos,Caballos,Pimienta,Pelusas,Olor,Cebolla"
}], [{
    "id": 1,
    "pregunta": "Top 10 personas m\u00e1s ricas",
    "respuesta": "Amancio Ortega,Bill Gates,David Koch,Mark Zuckerberg,Warren Buffett,Carlos Slim,Charles Koch,Larry Ellison,Jeff Bezos,Bernard Arnault"
}], [{
    "id": 4,
    "pregunta": "Actores principales de Harry Potter",
    "respuesta": "Daniel Radcliffe,Emma Watson,Harry Mellings,Rupert Grint,Tom Felton,Oliver Phelps,Fiona Shaw,Maggie Smith,Evanna Lynch,Jason Isaacs,Devon Murray,Ralph Fiennes,Jame Phelps,Gary Oldman,David Bradley,Matthew Lewis,Richard Griffiths,Michael Gambon,Alfred Enoch,Bonnie Wright,Alan Rickman,Richard Bremmer,Richard Harris,Helena Bonham Carter,Robbie Coltrane,Robert Pattinson"
}]
```

Comment: Lo que quieres no tiene sentido y es incorrecto porque no sería JSON válido. Quizás lo que te interesa no es quitar los corchetes de fuera sino los internos para que quede como un array de objetos (p.e. `[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`) que sí sería JSON válido y tendría más sentido desde el punto de vista funcional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que dices que quieres en la pregunta no tiene sentido y es incorrecto porque no sería JSON válido. Lo que tienes que hacer no es quitar los corchetes de fuera sino los internos para que quede como un array de objetos (p.e. `[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`) que sí sería JSON válido y tendría más sentido desde el punto de vista funcional.

El doble array se debe a que `Preguntas::where('id', '=', $valor)->get();` devuelve un array con objetos y no un objeto único (como se asume incorrectamente en el código). Entonces por eso al hacer `json_encode` te queda un array (`$ArrayTresPreguntas`) de arrays (`$Pregunta`). Por eso obtienes una estructura como ésta: `[ [{...}], [{...}], [{...}] ]`.

La solución sería quedarse con el primer valor del array `$Pregunta` (que por lo que parece sólo tiene una pregunta de todos modos). Para eso, sólo tendrías que cambiar la siguiente línea de código, de:

```
array_push($ArrayTresPreguntas,$Pregunta);
```

a

```
array_push($ArrayTresPreguntas,$Pregunta[0]);
```

Y de ese modo, en lugar de añadir un array a `ArrayTresPreguntas`, añadirás sólo el primer elemento. Y la estructura final después de `json_encode` se verá así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "pregunta": "Cosas que provocan estornudos",
        "respuesta": "Polvo,Comida,Irritaci\u00f3n nariz,Mocos,Canela,Virus,Contaminaci\u00f3n,Poluci\u00f3n,Resfriado,Flores,Catarro,Invierno,\u00c1caros,Perfume fuerte,Viento,Moho,Perros,H\u00famedad,H\u00e1mster,Conejos,Fumar,Especias,Heno,Guindilla,Constipado,Alergia a los \u00e1caros,Enfermedades,Lim\u00f3n,Polen,Naranja,Fr\u00edo,Infecci\u00f3n nasal,Pluma,Gripe,Bacterias,Pinos,Pelo,Aire fr\u00edo,Animales,Rinitis,Luz,Aire,Lluvia,Agua,Tierra,Escalofr\u00edo,Reflejos,Caballos,Pimienta,Pelusas,Olor,Cebolla"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "pregunta": "Top 10 personas m\u00e1s ricas",
        "respuesta": "Amancio Ortega,Bill Gates,David Koch,Mark Zuckerberg,Warren Buffett,Carlos Slim,Charles Koch,Larry Ellison,Jeff Bezos,Bernard Arnault"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "pregunta": "Actores principales de Harry Potter",
        "respuesta": "Daniel Radcliffe,Emma Watson,Harry Mellings,Rupert Grint,Tom Felton,Oliver Phelps,Fiona Shaw,Maggie Smith,Evanna Lynch,Jason Isaacs,Devon Murray,Ralph Fiennes,Jame Phelps,Gary Oldman,David Bradley,Matthew Lewis,Richard Griffiths,Michael Gambon,Alfred Enoch,Bonnie Wright,Alan Rickman,Richard Bremmer,Richard Harris,Helena Bonham Carter,Robbie Coltrane,Robert Pattinson"
    }
]
```

que sí es JSON válido (lo puedes comprobar en [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)) y que seguramente es la estructura que realmente estás buscando en lugar de la que pones en la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me entendiste a pesar de lo mal que me expliqué :S Genial gracias por el aporte! Me funcionó a la perfección y muy bien explicado a la vez.